# Looking for a linear actuator that can carry a transverse load? Does such a product exist?

Tags: motors, linear-motion, actuator, linear-motors, linear-systems

I am looking for a product that works like a linear actuator where you can control how far it extends but it can also hold a transverse load at the furthest point of extension.

What I am looking for would be similar to common consumer models such as this one found on amazon https://amzn.to/3At7ynu. It should be mounted on one end and still be able to hold the load of about 10 lbs at a distance of 45 inches (1150mm), basically a giant cantilever beam. Does such a product exist?

Comment: Custom. I don't think your approach would work anyways. A lead screw is heavy and not very stiff. You are going to need support wires and counterweights and junk. This is less an actuator problem and more a structural problem. Look at what tower cranes do.

Comment: You also did not specify your minimum reach.

Comment: Should be possible as a combination of guides and actuator.  Get your stroke from actuator and find an oversized guide rail that is only half extended at your max.  As long as you have no dimensional constraints on the guide rails, you have not constrained into the impossible.

Comment: You need to address several constraints - material, pole/arm size, deflection allowance, mounting details (on concrete, metal, or...). If no deflection limit, a telescopic fishing rod may suit.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to build a mechanism similar to a car engine lift.
It lifts and has resistance to lateral forces much greater than 10#.[image: car engine lift]